# "Type 'UIAlertController' has no member 'Style' "

Tags: uikit

Trying to create an alert box but an issue comes along saying "Type 'UIAlertController' has no member 'Style'"

```
@IBAction func showMessage (sender: UIButton) {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome to My First App",
message: "Hello World", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
    UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:nil))
       present(alertController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620092-init) has the following parameters:

```
convenience init(title: String?, 
         message: String?, 
  preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style)
```

The constants for UIAlertController.Style are actionSheet and alert. 
Thus you can just do the following (same applies for UIAlertAction):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Welcome to my First App",
            message: "Hello World",
            preferredStyle: .alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: nil))
```